# Memory - AVAIL bit VS PRESENT bit

Tags: memory, memory-management

As we know, in some system we have a bits to indicate if the physical address is in the memory or not - AVAIL bit and PRESENT bit. What is the diffrence between them? there is a situation, when the present bit it turn on, but the AVAIL is not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These bits are strongly architecture-dependent. An example where it could be useful to make use of those two would be:

- **AVAIL**: the page is available in volatile memory (i.e. RAM, ...). If not, it must be loaded from non-volatile memory (i.e. HDD, ...). This is commonly refered as *swapping*.
- **PRESENT**: the page entry if actually present in the TLB. As you may know it, some architectures use software-maintained TLBs and it could be convenient to know if a page is already loaded into it.